Prove that a test is most powerful when $X_1,\cdots,X_n\sim U(0,\theta)$
Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n\sim U(0,\theta),\theta >0$ be independent random variables. I want to prove that $\phi :\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,1]$ given by $\phi (x):=\begin{cases}1,&\theta _0<x_{(n)}\vee x_{(n)}\leq \theta _0\alpha ^{1/n}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ is a most powerful test of level $\alpha\in (0,1)$ to test $H:\theta=\theta _0$ vs $K:\theta =\theta _1>\theta _0$.

I was able to prove that $\phi$ has level $\alpha$. To prove that $\phi$ is most powerful I tried to use the Neyman-Pearson Lemma, but I failed.
First I tried to find a constant $k\geq 0$ such that $\phi (x)=\begin{cases}1,&f_{\theta_1}(x)>kf_{\theta_0}(x)\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in order to use the "sufficiency" part of NP Lemma. I know that with $k=(\theta _1/\theta _0)^n$ we can conclude that, given any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the inequality $f_{\theta_1}(x)>kf_{\theta_0}(x)$ implies that $\phi (x)=1$. However, I couldn't prove that, given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the equality $\phi (x)=1$ implies that $f_{\theta_1}(x)>kf_{\theta_0}(x)$.

My question is: How can I prove that the test $\phi$ is most powerful to test $H:\theta=\theta _0$ vs $K:\theta =\theta _1>\theta _0$.

The Neyman–Pearson lemma may not help if it is about a uniformly most powerful test, as here there are several tests with the same power: a rejection region of $x_{(n)} \ge \theta_0(1-\alpha)^{1/n} $ would have the same power as your example.

Do you have any idea how can I prove that $\phi$ is most powerful? I want to use this step to finally prove that $\phi$ is uniformly most powerful to test $H:\theta=\theta_0$ vs. $K:\theta\neq\theta_0$.

I do not think you can show it is the uniformly most powerful test here.  At best you can show it is a most powerful test along with many others when $K: \theta=\theta_1>\theta_0$.  Perhaps you can argue that, given $K$ and $\theta_1$ and $\alpha$, there is an upper bound on  the joint event of $0 \le x_{(n)} \le \theta_0$ and rejecting $H$ and there is an upper bound on  the joint event of $\theta_0 \lt x_{(n)}$ and rejecting $H$, so there is an upper bound on the event of rejecting $H$, i.e. on the power,  and your test achieves it.
